# Achieve android gmail tablet design in selection (arrow style)

Tags: android, android-fragments, tablet

I am trying to build a tablet optimized app and I would like to follow the same style of gmail tablet version in selections (the arrow on the right side of the selection). I don't know how to obtain the same style. There is a shadow and an arrow for the selection.

This is an image of gmail app: 
[image: Selection in GMail]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow is just part of the list item background.

Here is and example from the Email application where list_selected_holo is a drawable that contains an arrow on its right side (You can find the drawable with simple google search).

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_read_holo" />
</selector>
```

I would suggest looking at the open source Email application which now shares style with the Gmail application. ref: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email
Note that it takes some resources from external path which I couldn't find on github (frameworks/opt/mailcommon/res).

Comment: I've found those arrow drawables! You can download them from this page: https://code.google.com/r/jackyhopeful-shuffle/source/browse/shuffle-android/res/?r=f31711fe246bd363581a8429a4ea323511b82e64#res%2Fdrawable-sw600dp-xhdpi