# Draw an image outside the bounds of the container View

Tags: android, android-listview, drawable

I want to achieve this [Achieve android gmail tablet design in selection (arrow style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866308/achieve-android-gmail-tablet-design-in-selection-arrow-style) and I am thinking to a strategy to reach my purpose.

I would like to set on the list item a drawable selector with an arrow. In order to make it working, though, I need to draw outside the bounds of the List Item so I am asking here if anybody knows how to draw something outside the bounds of the container View. Is it possible? Is there a shift/translation property available?

Thanks
Tobia Loschiavo

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but off the top of my head, have you tried using negative margins on an ImageView inside of the list item?

Comment: No it doesn't work...the text or the image still obeys to the container bounds (tried with Relative Layout).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to draw outside the bounds of the view.  If you don't explicitly draw those border pixels, there will be nothing between the two views.

It's a visual trick.  So in the Gmail case, they simply draw a white triangle with two dark diagonal borders and no border on the right side on the selected row.  All other rows are drawn with a hard dark vertical border.  The content fragment on the right probably has no border drawn on its left side.  So there's an illusion of the arrow and the content view "bleeding" together.

Comment: so is the shadow an image on the right of the list item? but if this is true, whe should not have an image next to the listview borders (1px line) unless you have an image for the borders as well. Watching the gmail app, it seems that the list item is wider in "tablet" mode. So do they change the list item layouts and drawables according to the device orientation? it seems a bit complicated...But is the gmail tablet app the same gmail app we find on phones or is it a different one?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about the shadow.  The pixels that you see which make up the "shadow" are just part of the right-side border of the item rows.  So the unselected items have a border with a little drop shadow effect, which seamlessly connect to each other vertically, and the selected item does the same, except with a little white triangle jutting out of its border.

Comment: And yes, phones and tablets most likely use the same app with different layouts defined based on device attributes.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for an overview.

Comment: ok thanks, I was just saying that the listview separator (not border) between items should have the shadow on the right side as well right? I thought to this solution, but if you look at gmail app, it seems that the item of the listview on the phone is narrower than the tablet version one and this is unexplainable.

Comment: I have looked into the gmail apk and I found the arrow used as item selector. In drawable folder there is a png that is called email vertical divider (it seems the shadow) but it is not used in xml layout of the unselected row so I guess it is used programmatically. Since I can see the selector layout, I deduct that the shadow is not composed as part of the selector.